# Why am I getting this compiler error referencing a line from a different function?

Tags: c, function

I'm just trying to pass copywords from the function get_string in to fileinput in main.

the compiler says error in function get_string while referencing line 5 which is the first line of main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char get_string (char * copywords[100])
int main (){
char fileinput[100];
get_string(fileinput[100]);
;


char get_string (char * copywords[100]) {
FILE *fp;
int c;
char copywords[100];
fp = fopen("gues20.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
exit(1);
else {
while(fgets(copywords , 100, fp) == EOF){
}
fclose(fp);
}
return (copywords);
}
```

Comment: This code is a mess and won't even compile. Please clean your code up before asking people to debug it for you.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation?  It looks like your blocks don't close in the right places, but it's hard to be sure.

Comment: The source looks ugly. You might like to use the `indent` tool to beautify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a tool or editor which indent your code for you, you will see at a glance that there something odd. You are missing a `;` and that's a reason. Then, you put a `;` where likely a `}` should go, and so there is an unbalanced `{`. Do not underestimate how useful it could be for you and for any reader a well indented and presented code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char get_string (char * copywords[100]);

int main (){
    char fileinput[100];
    get_string(fileinput[100]);
}


char get_string (char * copywords[100]) {
    FILE *fp;
    int c;
    char copywords[100];  // redeclared
    fp = fopen("gues20.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(1);
    else {
        while(fgets(copywords , 100, fp) == EOF) ; // ??
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return copywords;  // (*)
}
```

Your code shows other errors, like redeclaring of `copywords`, returning a pointers (to a memory area that will be invalid) instead of a `char`. Briefly, your code **won't compile** and even if you strive to make it compilable, likely it won't do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a semicolon in the prototype for `get_string()`, right before `main()`.

```
char get_string (char * copywords[100]);
                                       ^
                                       |
                                   IMPORTANT
```

This causes the function definitions to nest, which is not allowed.

Comment: Is he also defining the implementation in `main`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a semicolon after the declaration of `get_string`, so the compiler doesn't know that the declaration is over and when it sees the `int` from `int main`, it gets confused because `int` isn't legal after the parameter list of a function declaration.

PS: Your main function also doesn't have a closing brace, but that's a different issue.